# Можно ли употребить фразеологизм "невооруженным глазом" в переносном значении?

Tags: фразеология

Основное и неоспоримое значение *невооруженным глазом* *(видеть, смотреть)* -- без оптических приборов. А можно ли этот фразеологизм употребить в таком контексте:

*То, что наши прадеды делали невооруженным глазом, сейчас осуществляется с помощью современных технологий.* (Речь идет о технологии производства водки, о классической рецептуре.)

Можно ли сказать *невооруженным глазом делать*? Значение в этом контексте можно так сформулировать: без измерительных приборов, не соблюдая точные пропорции, что ли...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > > Можно ли сказать невооруженным глазом делать? Значение в этом контексте можно так сформулировать: без измерительных приборов, не соблюдая точные пропорции, что ли...

Не думаю. Возможно вы смешали "невооруженным глазом" и "на глазок". В общем-то у этих фразеологизмов близкий смысл, но первый относится только к тому, что делается зрением, второй - ко всему, что угодно.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, лучше сказать так: *"То, что наши предки делали на глаз, сейчас..."* А ваш вариант я бы счёл за неверное употребление фразеологизма.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна, "невооруженным глазом делать" отпадает. А есть ли другие значения у этого фразеологизма?